# Powershell queries

Tags: powershell

1. Is there a command line bash's !$ (match last word of previous command)
2. any shortcut to delete previous word. Ex: cd D:\programs\scrap .`<ctrl+backspace>` deletes the word 'scrap'
3. Replace `<br>` tags with newlines in the output. I tried this:

   PS D:\program files\wamp\www\play> p .\delete.php | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "`<br>`", "\n"}

   1310210455\n13101240552218 //OUTPUT

which does replace the 
 with \n , but it doesn't create a newline.just a plain text \n. Fix?

4. cd d:\pro completes the directory name , but doesn't add a . Why? possible at all to fix it?

Thats all for now. powershell is really working for me now.
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) $$ will match the last token of the previous command. E.g.:

```
C:\PS> cd 'C:\Program Files'
C:\Program Files>$$
C:\Program Files
C:\Program Files>
```

2) `<ctrl+backspace>` will delete the previous word if you are using the PowerShell ISE, but the Windows console does not support deleting a previous word. You can run the ISE with the script pane hidden so there is only a command pane and output pane.

3) To put a newline in a string use ``n`. For your example:

```
PS D:\program files\wamp\www\play> p .\delete.php | Foreach-Object {$_ -replace "<br>", "`n"}
```

4) I'm not sure what your last question is. You say "but doesn't add a ." Is there something missing between the 'a' and the '.'? I'm assuming it's a '\'. If it is, you can add a backslash after the quote and continue to tab-complete. PowerShell will move the quote next time you tab. E.g.

`cd c:\pro<tab>` yields -> `cd 'C:\Program Files'` then,

`cd 'C:\Program Files'\mic<tab>` yields -> `cd 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft'`

Answer (score 0):

You can also do:

```
gc myfile.txt | %{$_ -replace '$`r`n','MyValue'}
```

So, the above will remove the carriage return from the end of the line and replace it with *MyValue*